# Next JS app - high Largest Contentful Paint showing huge hero image (mobile) in screenshot for initial page load

Tags: next.js, pagespeed, core-web-vitals, next-images, largest-contentful-paint

I'm completely stuck on getting my Hero Image to load efficiently and am using 'PageSpeed Insights' to measure... and really hope someone can help . I'm sure I'm not the only one that's had this issue before but I can't seem to find anything anywhere!

So here's my code for my hero component:

```
<div className="h-screen bg-[#ecf0f3] relative overflow-hidden">
      <Image
        src={blur}
        alt="blur"
        fill
        style={{ objectFit: "cover", position: "absolute" }}
        quality={100}
        sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 20vw"
        className="animate-pulse"
        loading="eager"
      />
      {/* // placeholder="blur"
        // blurDataURL="/blur-placeholder.png" */}
      {/* Main Text */}
      <div className="flex flex-col text-center mx-auto max-w-[1260px] items-center justify-center pt-28 md:pt-28">
<p>some title text here (cut short for this question)</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Heres the 'PageSpeed Insights' feedback:

blur

```
<img alt="blur" fetchpriority="high" loading="eager" decoding="async" data-nimg="fill" class="animate-pulse" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 20vw" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fblur.b947cdcf.png&amp;w=128&amp;q=100…" src="https://www.bloxywebservices.co.uk/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmed…" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px;">
```

and the screenshot is showing this:
[image: PageSpeed screenshot for initial load on mobile]

The image is really long so assume its preloading the wrong image size??

I feel like I'm going crazy and have been trying to sort this for hours so any help will be massively appreciated!!

Here's my site i'm working on: https://www.bloxywebservices.co.uk/
repo here: https://github.com/sbloxy123/my-freelance-site
link for Pagespeen Insights: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-bloxywebservices-co-uk/lqjji5a1xw?form_factor=mobile

Thanks in advance, let me know if I've missed anything, I don't post often!

---

I've tried a number of things but nothing has come close to changing the length of the image as shown on mobile.

- tried lazy loading
- tried moving css into style={..}  rather than className.
- tried changing various css properties - positions, sizes, object-fit.
- reduced image size

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm not able to reproduce today on the URL you gave. For future reference, you might find https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/discussions a helpful place to ask this kind of question.